# Is there an explanation to the usage of complex exponential in Fourier series and Fourier Transform?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

Could the use of a complex rotating  phasor for Fourier Series and Transforms be mathematically justified ?  Why are we using a complex exponential in the Fourier Transform? Let us suppose there is a  vector r in a circle whose tail is at the origin and  the head of the vector is at a point p(x,y) and making an angle theta w.r.t to the horizontal x axis. This rotating action can be simply achieved by changing the angle theta and the vector moves around the circle. This rotating action of the vector , will produce the equivalent sine function. Why are we going for a complex exponential in the fourier transform? I understand that the complex exponential also does the same thing and so would any vector r (as mentioned above).  Further, the horizontal component of the vector r, along the x axis is r*cos(theta) and the vertical component of the vector r is r*sin( theta).  If you add these , you should get to the head of the vector r.  Why would I need to introduce the complex number "i" here , I,e  r*cos(theta) + i*r*sin(theta)?  I am unable to understand the use of a complex number here and how is it different from the normal vector "r"(mentioned in the example above), as far as the rotating action is concerned.

I am also aware that r*e^(i* theta) is equal to r*cos(theta)+ i*r*sin(theta).  This is the Euler's complex exponential. It would be helpful if one could explain as to why we use complex number here instead of any other normal vector such as "r " mentioned in the above paragraph. You could as well achieve this rotating action by varying the angle theta  of that vector "r" and this rotating action enables you to describe the given f(t) in terms of the sine(theta) or the cosine(theta) respectively

Comment: That's because we can. If facts known since Euler aren't an acceptable answer for you, I'm afraid you can't be helped, not at this site.

Comment: Thank you @ProfessorVector.   Whether i accept or i don't accept , the facts remain.  I am only trying to analyse the difference between a complex exponential and a normal rotating vector.  How do you justify the usage of a complex number was the question !!  Thank you for the answer anyhow

Comment: You seem to be using the word "justify" in the sense of "show that there is no other way to solve the problem", whereas most people reading your title will think you mean "show that this way of solving the problem will always produce correct results." Do you see the difference in those two readings?

Comment: @David K : Thank you for your response. I will change the title , so that it does not mislead the readers.

Comment: @David K : The focus can be on the word "rotating phasor". I have always seen a complex representation for that. However, i am trying to analyse the difference between such complex phasors and vectors(without the complex term. i,e without the "i" or the "j"), where the rotating action could still be achieved using such vectors by simply varying the angle theta that they make w.r.t the x axis..

Answer (score 2):

As with many other things, the answer is because we can and because we find it convenient.

Complex exponentials are certainly **not** the only way to do the job of a Fourier transform. Fourier himself did not use them.
Instead, Fourier developed a cosine transform and a sine transform.

One form of a cosine transform is

$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos(2\pi kt) f(t)\,\mathrm dt $$

and the corresponding sine transform is

$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin(2\pi kt) f(t)\,\mathrm dt. $$

The cosine and sine functions here are the components of a unit vector that makes and angle $2\pi kt$ counterclockwise from the positive $x$ axis.

Go ahead and use these transforms if you want.
Many people do.

The people who use the complex exponential form of Fourier analysis do so because they find it convenient and because it is just as mathematically sound as the cosine and sine transforms.

Comment: :.  Thank you so much for such a detailed explanation.